# Use const_cast to implement the move constructor

Tags: c++

I have read [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Move_Constructor) page about the move constructor. In that article, it use the template `proxy` to modify the  temporary variable returned from function.

This is the implemention.

```
namespace detail {

    template <class T>
    struct proxy
    {
        T *resource_;
    };
} // detail

template <class T>
class MovableResource
{
private:
    T * resource_;

public:
    explicit MovableResource (T * r = 0) : resource_(r) { }
    ~MovableResource() throw() { delete resource_; }   // Assuming std:::auto_ptr like behavior.

    MovableResource (MovableResource &m) throw () // The "Move constructor" (note non-const parameter)
    : resource_ (m.resource_)
    {
        m.resource_ = 0; // Note that resource in the parameter is moved into *this.
    }

    MovableResource (detail::proxy<T> p) throw () // The proxy move constructor
    : resource_(p.resource_)
    {
        // Just copying resource pointer is sufficient. No need to NULL it like in the move constructor.
    }

    MovableResource & operator = (MovableResource &m) throw () // Move-assignment operator (note non-const parameter)
    {
        // copy and swap idiom. Must release the original resource in the destructor.
        MovableResource temp (m); // Resources will be moved here.
        temp.swap (*this);
        return *this;
    }

    MovableResource & operator = (detail::proxy<T> p) throw ()
    {
        // copy and swap idiom. Must release the original resource in the destructor.
        MovableResource temp (p);
        temp.swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }

    void swap (MovableResource &m) throw ()
    {
        std::swap (this->resource_, m.resource_);
    }

    operator detail::proxy<T> () throw () // A helper conversion function. Note that it is non-const
    {
        detail::proxy<T> p;
        p.resource_ = this->resource_;
        this->resource_ = 0;     // Resource moved to the temporary proxy object.
        return p;
    }
};
```

What about just add a constructor taking a const reference and use `const_cast` to change the variable to implement the move semantics like this.

```
MovableResource(const MovableResource& m)
{
    MovableResource& afterM = const_cast<MovableResource&>(m);
    afterM.swap(*this);
}
```

Does this introduce undefined behavior?

Comment: Your "move" constructor is actually a *copy* constructor, using it for "movement" changes the semantics. And there is often a reason that objects are marked as constant, casting it away may indeed lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: In the old c++ standard, We need copy constructor like this to implement the move constructor, right? And I want to know does this will lead to undefined behavior. Yes? or no?

Comment: @xsj0jsx Implementing copy constructor using swap would be wrong in any C++ standard.

Comment: But we are implementing a class like `std::auto_ptr`, which have move semantics in its copy constructor

Comment: A class like your needs to be *very* well documented, because it changes the semantics and expectations of the copy-constructor. The big problem is your wish to cast away the const-ness of an object, and modify it. Technically it's *always* UB to modify a constant object, but you might get away with it *sometimes*, and it will be unpredictable when it will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing move semantics under the hood of a copy constructor interface is just asking for trouble. By using `const_cast` you are effectively fooling clients of your interface into believing that your constructor will leave `m` unmodified when it ends up clobbering its value. Consider the following code:

```
const MovableResource first(/* Some resource 'A' */);
MovableResource second(first);
// 'first', supposedly 'const' now has potentially a different value!
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was just thinking how to solve the problem like this:`MovableResource<int> func();  MovableResource<int> a(func());`

Answer (score 0):

> MovableResource (MovableResource &m) throw () // The "Move constructor" (note non-const parameter)

That is not a **move** constructor, that is a **copy** constructor.  A proper **move** constructor takes an rvalue reference as input:

```
MovableResource (MovableResource &&m) throw ()
```

> MovableResource & operator = (MovableResource &m) throw () // Move-assignment operator (note non-const parameter)

Likewise, that is a **copy** assignment operator.  A proper **move** assignment operator takes an rvalue reference as input:

```
MovableResource & operator = (MovableResource &&m) throw ()
```

Comment: What i want is to  transfer the ownership of a resource held by an object to another object in C++03. Your code can only be implemented in c++11, right?

Comment: @xsj0jsx: Have a look at [Boost.Move](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/move.html), it provides C++11 style move semantics in C++03.